# Filtering C# dictionaries

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a C# dictionary with a key of statecode and a list of a classtype. Is there away I can take only those dictionary items that have a FilnameId = 7 , and copy only those items to a second dictionary? I would like to do this without iterating through the dictionary if possible. Any and all direction would be most appreciated. My dictionary and class are below.

-Jason

```
public class FirstReportsData
{
    public FirstReportsData() { }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Policy { get; set; }
    public int FileNameId { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }

}

Dictionary<string, List<FirstReportsData>> dicFsrFileNameId1 = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<FirstReportsData>>();
```

Comment: Use a `Where` clause?

Comment: You can use LINQ, where you use where to filter the dictionary items with a FilenameId of 7 and copy them into a new dictionary. The following answers are of reference value. But even with LINQ, Dictionary will still be traversed. It's just that you don't have to write redundant for loops anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to filter a dictionary by values properties without iterating through all items...even if you use Linq, there will still be a iteration happening behind the scene

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you mean by "iterating". If you don't want to write `for`/`foreach` loops then you can go with LINQ:

```cs
var result = dicFsrFileNameId1
    .Values
    .SelectMany(d => d)
    .Where(d => d.FileNameId == 7)
    .ToList();
```

If you need to rebuild the dictionary then use `GroupBy`:

```cs
var resDict = dicFsrFileNameId1
    .Values
    .SelectMany(d => d)
    .Where(d => d.FileNameId == 7)
    .GroupBy(d => d.StateCode)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Otherwise no, since your data structure is not a dictionary from `FileNameId` to collection of files, you will need to go through all the `FirstReportsData` stored in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As previously has been mentioned, may you don't want to make a traditional for loops but iteration will run under the hood.

you can use:

```
Dictionary<string, List<FirstReportsData>> dicFsrFileNameId1 = new Dictionary<string, List<FirstReportsData>>();


List<FirstReportsData> list = new List<FirstReportsData>();
list.Add(new FirstReportsData() { Id = 1, FileNameId = 1, Policy = "Fake", StateCode = "Fake" });
list.Add(new FirstReportsData() { Id = 2, FileNameId = 2, Policy = "Fake", StateCode = "Fake" });
list.Add(new FirstReportsData() { Id = 3, FileNameId = 3, Policy = "Fake", StateCode = "Fake" });
list.Add(new FirstReportsData() { Id = 4, FileNameId = 4, Policy = "Fake", StateCode = "Fake" });
list.Add(new FirstReportsData() { Id = 5, FileNameId = 5, Policy = "Fake", StateCode = "Fake" });
list.Add(new FirstReportsData() { Id = 6, FileNameId = 6, Policy = "Fake", StateCode = "Fake" });
list.Add(new FirstReportsData() { Id = 7, FileNameId = 7, Policy = "Fake", StateCode = "Fake" });


dicFsrFileNameId1.Add("test", list);

Dictionary<string, List<FirstReportsData>> dicFsrFileNameId2 = new Dictionary<string, List<FirstReportsData>>();

dicFsrFileNameId2.Add("testOut", dicFsrFileNameId1.Select(o => o.Value).First().Where(o => o.FileNameId == 7).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

This code converts directly into a dictionary with the same structure. Technically, it is an iteration, but there is no for loop. It preserves the same structure and takes into account that the StateCode value is always the same for each list in the input dictionary.

```cs
    var otherDictionary = dicFsrFileNameId1
            .Values
            .Select(dataList => dataList.Where(data => data.FileNameId == 7).ToList())
            .ToDictionary(data => data.First().StateCode, data => data);
```